# How to generate a PDF or markup from OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an OpenAPI 3.0 spec and I want to generate a PDF out of it so that it can be given to the end users.

Currently, tools like [swagger-spec-to-pdf](https://github.com/agreatfool/swagger-spec-to-pdf) or [swagger2markup](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup) only support Swagger 2.0 but not OpenAPI 3.0. Is it possible to generate a PDF from an OpenAPI 3.0 spec without converting it to Swagger 2.0?

Comment: List of OpenAPI tooling - https://openapi.tools/

Comment: You can check apibake: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apibake

Answer (score 31):

A possible solution is to convert your OpenAPI 3.0 definition to an HTML doc, then use a browser's "Save to PDF" feature to convert HTML to PDF.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to https://editor.swagger.io.
2. Paste your OpenAPI 3.0 YAML/JSON definition.
3. Select **Generate Client > html**.
4. Download & unzip the file.
5. Open the `index.html` page in a browser, e.g. Chrome.
6. Select **File > Print**, change the **Destination** to **Save as PDF**, and save the page.

Comment: Fyi, there's the 'openapi-generator-gradle-plugin' which makes steps 1 to 4 incl redundant.

Comment: There's a lot of generators in openapitools/openapi-generator-cli (docker image), but none of them are PDF.

Answer (score 11):

I just found [RapiPDF](https://mrin9.github.io/RapiPdf/) which is able to generate PDF from OpenAPI 3.0 definition.

But it still isn't an ideal tool I'm looking for. I found these limitations so far:

- No CLI, runs only in browser. So I can't use it in an automate pipeline.
- Callback is not supported
- No example in generated document

Comment: It also doesn't support many of the features of OpenAPI 3. It seems to fall flat on OneOf or AnyOf.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this site](https://www.swdoc.org/) and post your OpenAPI 3.0 spec (in json) directly into it. It's the easiest way, I think and the generated PDF looks pretty.

Comment: Didn't do it well at all using an  OpenAPI "3.0.1" spec with 3 definitions

Comment: That didn't render any operation at all

Answer (score 4):

ApiBake - Convert OpenAPI to PDF: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apibake
I'm the developer of the tool.

2023 UPDATE: The tool has been converted from Dart to Node.js, added yaml support, fixed a few issues. Added customizable config/styling (for now mostly color scheme configuration).

The focus of the project is to generate visually simple, yet useful document, with bookmarks and type links for easy navigation. I.e. object definitions in the PDF are easy to copy and use in TypeScript/JavaScript code. Now working on custom styling of the output document. Feedback is welcome.

Comment: This looked useful for my usecase, but only supports JSON.  Any plans to add YAML support?

Comment: I converted an openapi yaml spec to json from swagger editor to try this tool but getting the error "invalid openapi json file". It'll be good to add an example on the homepage itself for more clarity on expected input.

Comment: No source, just an executable download? No good.

Comment: Is it 3.x.x openapi json? The tool only supports 3.x.x version. Actually, you are right. Will open the sources.

Comment: Showed "invalid openapi json file" for valid files and the output is visually quite poor unfortunately

Comment: @zed this issue should be fixed in the latest update

Answer (score 3):

The following 2 packages helped me generate a PDF from OpenAPI json file:

- org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:5.0.0-beta2
- org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-jvm-pdf:3.2.0

Apply the relevant *Plugin* classes and the rest is pretty straight-forward task configuration. This is my groovy plugin but it shouldn't be difficult to find the corresponding gradle DSL extensions should you need to.

```
project.plugins.apply OpenApiGeneratorPlugin
GenerateTask adoc = project.tasks.withType(GenerateTask).iterator().next()
adoc.with {
    it.input = swagger.outputDir.path + '/' + swagger.outputFileName + '.json'
    it.generatorName.set 'asciidoc'
    it.outputDir.set swagger.outputDir.path

    // Leaving the below option empty can cause rendering issues
    it.configOptions.putAll([
        'infoUrl'  : 'https://example.com',
        'infoEmail': 'inbox@example.com',
    ])
}

project.plugins.apply AsciidoctorJPdfPlugin
project.tasks.withType(AsciidoctorPdfTask).iterator().next().with {
    it.sourceDir = adoc.outputDir
    it.outputDir = it.sourceDir
}
```

Let me know if there are questions about (or syntax errors in) this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and nicest solution I found it is just using the usual https://editor.swagger.io/. Once you are happy with the generated outcome (on the right), just drag the central cursor on the left (to cover your source code) in order to visualise only the final documentation. Then if you use Chrome (similarly for Firefox), just (right button in the screen or from menu) choose "Print" and for "Destination" select "Save As PDF".

Comment: That requires lots of clicking and expanding schemas, and so it is not very reproducible.

Comment: lots of clicks? eventually the opposite. Not reproducible? what you mean? it is not meant to be a "programmatic" method of course

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenApi generators to generate documentation in html or asciidoc format. Then transform the asciidoc into PDF.

If your specification is automatically generated based on classes, as in springdoc in the SpringBoot application, you can write a unit test that saves the specification from raised during test phase. And then, during the package phase, generate documentation

Example for maven:

```xml
    <properties>
        <!--
            Default asciidoctor dependencies conflicted, use solution from
            https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/blob/main/asciidoctor-pdf-example/pom.xml
        -->
        <asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version>2.2.4</asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version>
        <asciidoctorj.pdf.version>2.3.9</asciidoctorj.pdf.version>
        <asciidoctorj.version>2.5.10</asciidoctorj.version>
        <jruby.version>9.4.2.0</jruby.version>
    </properties>

<!-- ... -->

        <plugin>
            <!--
            OpenApi provides generators for generation documentation
            https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators#documentation-generators
            -->
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>open-api-doc-html</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/api-doc.json</inputSpec>
                        <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-doc/html</output>
                        <!-- https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/html/ -->
                        <generatorName>html</generatorName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>open-api-doc-html2</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/api-doc.json</inputSpec>
                        <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-doc/html2</output>
                        <!-- https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/html2/ -->
                        <generatorName>html2</generatorName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>open-api-doc-asciidoc</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/api-doc.json</inputSpec>
                        <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-doc/asciidoc</output>
                        <!-- https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/asciidoc/ -->
                        <generatorName>asciidoc</generatorName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
                    <version>${asciidoctorj.pdf.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Comment this section to use the default jruby artifact provided by the plugin -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jruby</artifactId>
                    <version>${jruby.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Comment this section to use the default AsciidoctorJ artifact provided by the plugin -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
                    <version>${asciidoctorj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-doc/asciidoc</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-doc/pdf</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-pdf-doc</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <backend>pdf</backend>
                        <attributes>
                            <source-highlighter>rouge</source-highlighter>
                            <icons>font</icons>
                            <pagenums/>
                            <toc/>
                            <idprefix/>
                            <idseparator>-</idseparator>
                        </attributes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```